# Creating Normal Windows Forms using Microsoft Expression Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, forms, expression-blend

I am going to make my project from Visual C#(Visual Studio 2010).. So i want some nice interfaces for my projects..

So that i have heard that Microsoft Expression Studio got the ability to make those nice interfaces.. Now Microsoft Expression Studio software is installed with me..

I Have 2 Questions..

1) My first question is can i create normal windows forms(Not WPF forms) with this scenario using Microsoft Expression Studio...?

2)Though yes or no i have prior experience of creating Windows forms from Visual Studio... can you give me some **Tutorial Links(Video/Others)**  to this scenario...

Its better if its possible in normal forms without using WPF because i dont have any knowlage about WPF... *And this is not a Web application this is Stand alone application..*

Comment: No, Expression doesn't support Winforms.  If you have no experience with either Winforms or WPF then it makes sense to only focus on learning WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression Blend is for WPF only.

You can try third party apps like [Tekerik's VisualStyleBuilder](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/tools-visual-style-builder-overview.html)  for Winforms.

However, if this is a new application you may want to invest some time and learn [WPF](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/5-Reasons-to-Never-Build-another-Winforms-Application.aspx).   There are some great [Tutorials](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx) and [Books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672331195) on WPF out there.

Plus learning XAML will be helpful in building [Windows 8 Metro apps](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/bursteg/Part-4-Windows-8-Camp-Introduction-to-Building-Metro-Apps-Part-4).